# Windows Phone Dev: Play internal mp3 files with winmm.dll

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mp3, winmm

I need an help about the performing of the mp3 player files. I search on internet and i find how to use the winmm.dll libreary only if I need to take an mp3 file from an external directory. I need to modify it for an internal directory of my app.

Let's show the code:

I create the Mp3Player class like that:

```
class Mp3Player : IDisposable 
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, StringBuilder lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

    public void open(string file)
    {
        const string FORMAT = @"open ""{0}"" type MPEGVideo alias MyMp3";
        string command = String.Format(FORMAT, file);
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
    }

    public void play()
    {
        string command = "play MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        string command = "stop MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        string command = "close MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
    }

    public double Duration()
    {
        string command = "status MyMp3 length";
        double bho = mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
        return bho;
    }
```

And call for open the internal file here:

```
var soundfile = "Assets/audio/myaudio.mp3";
private Mp3Player _mp3player = new Mp3Player();
_mp3player.open(soundfile);
_mp3player.play();
```

This give me an error on the opening of the of the file, so i'm sure that the problem is in the directory path that i send to the class. I tryed some version but no one works and on internet can't find nothing helping me. Some one of you can say me the correct path for making work that function?

Thank you very much to all.

Excuse me for my really bad english.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c5bd628e-f4b2-4c40-b478-a9a8aef640eb/cant-find-pinvoke-dll-winmmdll-?forum=windowsmobiledev) on Windows Mobile, all waveform audio function are implemented in 'coredll.dll'. Use this DLL instead of 'winmm.dll'.

Comment: I try to change it, but i still think that the problem is on the path that i write: "Assets/audio/myaudio.mp3", you know the right path to use?